# Caractere inesperado no CountdownJS

Tags: javascript

Estou a usar uma contagem regressiva (Countdown) em minha página. Depois de algumas pesquisas achei o [CountdownJS](http://countdownjs.org/). Fui seguindo [este tutorial](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/12/12/countdown/) até que me dei conta que mesmo sem alterar nada no código do script que baixei do [Site Oficial](http://countdownjs.org/) ele exibe um erro no console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Realmente há um caractere errado no código ou é alguma configuração que precisa ser feita no ambiente?**

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Countdown</title>
</head>
<body>
    Countdown until 2050  
    <h1 id="countdown-holder"></h1> 

    <script src="countdown.js"></script>
    <script>  
      var clock = document.getElementById("countdown-holder")  
        , targetDate = new Date(2050, 00, 01); // Jan 1, 2050;  

      clock.innerHTML = countdown(targetDate).toString();  
      setInterval(function(){  
        clock.innerHTML = countdown(targetDate).toString();  
      }, 1000);  
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT:** https://bitbucket.org/mckamey/countdown.js/raw/tip/countdown.js

Comment: em `<script src="js/countdown.js"></script>` você não deve ter adicionado corretamente o valor em `src="js/countdown.js"`, verifique o caminho real do script e substitua `js/countdown.js` por ele, esse erro acontece porque countdown não existe ainda e você esta tentando usa-lo em seu código.

Comment: O caminho está correto, já foi alterado! Seguindo sua teoria, talvez eu esteja escrevendo em um lugar errado, vendo que uso o Yeoman e ele tem umas peculiaridades sobre isto. Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: isso ela pode estar em um scopo diferente

Comment: Não, o erro continua! Desta vez tenho certeza que não está nada errado com os diretórios e escopos. Lembro-me que este erro já ocorreu quando tentei usar essa esse objeto antes do ponto e vírgula. Não entendo bem! :/

Comment: teria como postar o código para analisarmos?

Comment: Tem certeza que a resposta do @SilvioAndorinha resolveu seu problema? Porque na prática ela não altera o seu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui você usou virgula e o correto seria ponto e virgula

```
  var clock = document.getElementById("countdown-holder")  // nessa linha
    , targetDate = new Date(2050, 00, 01); // Jan 1, 2050;  // nessa linha
```

o correto seria

```
 var clock = document.getElementById("countdown-holder");  
 targetDate = new Date(2050, 00, 01); // Jan 1, 2050;
```

Comment: A vírgula é [totalmente válida no `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Neste caso sua alteração não faz muita diferença, mas em outro escopo poderia estar criando uma variável global indevidamente.

Comment: @bfavaretto tem razão, então porque ele me deu um certo?

Comment: Aí eu não sei, tem que perguntar pra ele :) Ah, caso não tenha ficado claro, o -1 é meu porque a resposta transmite uma informação incorreta ok?

Comment: @bfavaretto sim tudo bem eu não sabia que com a virgula funcionava normal, mas não entendo em que eu ajudei ele porque ele abandonou a questão e me deu um certo.

Comment: Perguntei pra ele lá em cima.

Comment: @bfavaretto não sei se isso altera muita coisa mas acho que ele devia colocar o código script e o import fora do body

Comment: Se ele colocar depois do `</body>` é inválido; se ele passar pro `<head>`, vai dar erro no `getElementById`. Está ok assim.

Comment: @bfavaretto e se ele por entre o head e o body?

Comment: Também é inválido!

Comment: @bfavaretto estranho porque eu sempre fiz e faço assim e da certo.